# Selenium:error:package com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven does not exist

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, groovy, automation, version

I recently upgraded selenium version from2.x.x to 4.0.0 and now I am not able to compile the project and get below error:

> error:package com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven does not exist

Can you please suggest what changes should be done here?

Comment: There is such big differences between <2.5 and 4 that you potentially will have to rewrite a large part of your code. Are you using RC ? Also see here: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3974

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am not using RC tough, however, my project had the package "com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven" in many of my classes.

Comment: Can someone suggest ways to update from 2. x.x to 4.0.0 in maven project and how to fix the errors?